# Can't filter by name on Github multi branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm not sure what I am missing but I can't either **Filter by name (with regular expression)** or **Filter by name (with wildcards)** to match any branches. Even with the default **.*** Discover branches works fine. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8):

I just figured out what I was missing. You have to have both Discover and filter for it to work. Sigh...

Comment: can you give an example here. I have checked both options and used regex expressions to build multiple branches but it doesn't works for me

Answer (score -1):

You have to choose both of these options, for example:

[image]